# Subversive Eclipse Error - Switch Operation Failed.

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive

I have just started to use SVN and have run into a bit of trouble. I dont really know what to do about the following error:

> Switch operation failed.
>   svn: Failed to add file '.classpath': an unversioned file of the same name already exists

I tried switching from my branch to my trunk and then back to my branch. Now I cant switch to either. Any help would be much appreciated as I am a complete noob when it comes to SVN. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your file system there exists a file named `.classpath` which is not in your SVN. But in your SVN branch there is also a `.classpath` file.

I would talk to the team if you want to store the .classpath`-file in the SVN or hold an individual one for each developer outside the SVN.

What I would do:

1. Rename your local `.classpath` to e.g. `.classpath_local`
2. than checkout the one from the SVN and compare both files.
3. If you can live with the one from the SVN, fine, if not talk to the other team members if you should remove it from the SVN so that everyone can have its own version.